# OpenAM Policy Agent is unable to match URL

Tags: openam

I'm trying to protect a web application with OpenAM Policy Agent 3.3.0 on an Apache web server.

The application uses the following URL-styles:

```
http://my.host.name/appname/some/static/contents
http://my.host.name/appname/some?dynamic=content
http://my.host.name/appname/?interesting_query;with_data
```

I can successfully handle the first two with the following match patterns

```
http://my.host.name/appname/*
http://my.host.name/appname/*?*
```

but I'm failing to find a pattern that matches the last URL-style.
I already tried:

```
http://my.host.name/appname/?*
http://my.host.name/appname*?*
```

The OpenAM docs give me no clue how to handle this type.

What would be the correct matching pattern for this URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug (https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-3667) in the agents, which means that if you have a "/?" in your URLs, you will be unable to evaluate policies against those resources, they will always result in a deny. This issue was tackled in the end on both the agent and AM side, so you will most likely would need to upgrade to Agents-3.3.1 and 11.0.1 releases (both of them are only available to subscription customers).

Comment: Thanks Peter for clarifying. Can that change for OPENAM-3667 be found in trunk of OPENAM repository?

Comment: Since the issue has Resolved status, the answer is yes.